# How to output or copy from lc3 console outout into txt file

Tags: lc3

How can I save lc3 console output into a .txt file? The console does not let me copy or do anything with its output, please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the program which produces output that you want to display into LC3 Simulator
2. Go to File ---> Start Console File...

This will bring up a window that will allow you to choose where you want to save the text file that will contain the output. You can name it anything that you like but be sure to include the .txt extension on the end.

3. Run the program as usual
4. When the output that you want to save has successfully been printed to the console go to File ---> End Console File

If you go to the location you specified in step 2 you should now see a text file containing the console output.